# How to use user ID as parameter for custom authentication annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations, spring-expression

I've a REST API:

```
   @CurrentUserAccessLevel(userId = "#studentId")
   @GetMapping(value = "/{course-code}/users/{student-id}")
   public UserCourseDetailsDto getUserCourseDetails(@PathVariable(value = "course-code") final Long courseCode,
                                                    @PathVariable(value = "student-id") final Long studentId) {
       return userCourseService.getUserCourseDetails(studentId, courseCode);
   }
```

and custom authentication annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@PreAuthorize("@applicationUserDetailsService.hasAccessToResourceOwnedBy(#userId)")
public @interface CurrentUserAccessLevel {
    String userId();
}
```

the annotation uses method hasAccessToResourceOwnedBy(userId):

```
public boolean hasAccessToResourceOwnedBy(final Long userId) {
        final User currentUser = userService.resolveCurrentUser();
        return isAdmin(currentUser) || Objects.equals(currentUser.getId(), userId);
    }
```

but I'm getting null as userId. However, if I replace

```
@PreAuthorize("@applicationUserDetailsService.hasAccessToResourceOwnedBy(#userId)")
```

with

```
@PreAuthorize("@applicationUserDetailsService.hasAccessToResourceOwnedBy(#studentId)")
```

I obtain requested user id.

Basically, I need this annotation to avoid horizontal escalation of privileges, maybe there is some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Think that it is because meta-annotation supported by the spring security just simply allowing users to use a self-defined annotation (i.e   `@CurrentUserAccessLevel`) to refer a `@PreAuthorize(xxxxx)` and there are no fancy behaviour about using the attribute of the self-defined annotation (i.e `userId` attribute of `@CurrentUserAccessLevel`) to do some dynamic security configuration something like what you are trying to do. So the `userId` of the `@CurrentUserAccessLevel` is useless and you can remove it.

The `#userId` in the `@PreAuthorize` 's expression refer to the parameter name of the method that are annotated with `@CurrentUserAccessLevel`. So it works if you change it to `#studentId` as the `getUserCourseDetails()` has a method parameter name `Long studentId`

If you do not want to change the parameter name of the method to `userId` , you can use [`@P`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#using_method_parameters) to specify its value likes :

```java
@CurrentUserAccessLevel
public UserCourseDetailsDto getUserCourseDetails( Long courseCode, @P("userId") Long studentId){
  
}
```